# Determine the inequalities from the text

Tags: linear-programming, word-problem, operations-research

We have to give a mathematical model for the following problem.

> There is a company with two locations. For the production of two 
>   different products, it uses one base material where only $20$ units
>   are available per day. The first product is partly produced at the
>   first location, and partly produced at the second location. The second
>   product is only produced at the first location. The machines at the
>   first location cannot work more than $12$ hours, and the machines of
>   the second location cannot work more than $16$ hours.
>
> For the production of the first product, $2$ units of the base
>   material are used, for the second product $4$ units.
>
> At the first location, you need $2$ hours for the first product and
>   for the second product $2$ hours. At the second location, $4$ hours
>   for first product and $0$ hours for second (thus it's not produced
>   here).
>
> For every piece of the first product, you get $2000$ USD and for every
>   piece of the second product, you get $3000$ USD. How many pieces  of
>   the different products does the company have to produce each day,  in
>   order to achieve the maximum profit (by respecting all the constraints)?

I need to find the linear system of inequalities and the other constraints. Here is my solution but I'm not sure if it's alright?

$$
\begin{align}
  2x+4y &\leq 12 && \mbox{Time constraint location 1}\\
  2x+0y &\leq 16 && \mbox{Time constraint location 2}\\
  x,y &\geq 0    && \mbox{Non-negativity constraints}
\end{align}
$$
And the prices were also given, so here is the inequality for the profit:

$z(x,y) = 2000x + 3000y$

Is there anything I did wrong / missed?

Comment: You forgot to include the constraint that models the limited availability of base material. The first product uses 2 units, the second product uses 4 units and there are 20 units available, thus $2x+4y \leq 20$. Furthermore, the time constraint for the first location is incorrect since the second product only takes 2 hours instead of 4. There is a similar issue with the time constraint for the second location.